# sql server break columns into row with join

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am joining 2 tables here i am doing like

```
select distinct Package_id, package_title, durationindays,videourl,package_image_1,package_image_2,package_image_3,package_image_4,
package_image_5, Rating, AdultPrice
from packages
inner join
rates_and_dates on rates_and_dates.package = packages.package_id
where package_id=1 and adultprice='4500'
```

and the result comes like this

```
ID | Package_title | DurationInDays | VideoUrl | Package_Image_1 | Package_Image_2          |Package_Image_3   | Package_Image_4  | Package_Image_5
001 | Title | 5 | www.youtube.com?1231 | www.images.com/image1 | www.images.com/image2     | wwww.images.com/image3 | www.images.com/image4 | image5
```

note: all the images comes in different columns

i want to create only one column for all 5 images, so the result should come like this

```
ID  |Package_title|DurationInDays | VideoUrl           | Package_Images        |
001 |Title        |5              | www.youtube.com?123| www.images.com/image1 |
    |             |               |                    | www.images.com/image2 |
    |             |               |                    | www.images.com/image3 |
    |             |               |                    | www.images.com/image4 |
    |             |               |                    | image5                |
```

please help me to get this.
Thank you

Comment: you can use use union

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct Package_id, package_title, durationindays,videourl,package_image_1 + ',' + package_image_2 + ',' + package_image_3 + ',' + package_image_4 + ',' + package_image_5 As Pacakage,  Rating, AdultPrice
from packages
inner join
rates_and_dates on rates_and_dates.package = packages.package_id
where package_id=1 and adultprice='4500'
```

You can use any delimiter instead of comma.

Comment: i think this will work for me. But can't i achieve the same i want?

Comment: here someone did exactly what i want but it is very complex, @Muthu suggest me an easy way. Thank you.

Comment: Hi You can Put Char(13) instead of ',', so that each column will come in the next line, but while showing in management studio it will show them as single line.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "UNION ALL" to accomplish this.

```
select distinct Package_id, package_title, durationindays,videourl,package_image_1 as package_image, Rating, AdultPrice
from packages
inner join
rates_and_dates on rates_and_dates.package = packages.package_id
where package_id=1 and adultprice='4500'
UNION ALL
select distinct Package_id, package_title, durationindays,videourl,package_image_2 as package_image, Rating, AdultPrice
from packages
inner join
rates_and_dates on rates_and_dates.package = packages.package_id
where package_id=1 and adultprice='4500'
UNION ALL
select distinct Package_id, package_title, durationindays,videourl,package_image_3 as package_image, Rating, AdultPrice
from packages
inner join
rates_and_dates on rates_and_dates.package = packages.package_id
where package_id=1 and adultprice='4500'
UNION ALL
select distinct Package_id, package_title, durationindays,videourl,package_image_4 as package_image, Rating, AdultPrice
from packages
inner join
rates_and_dates on rates_and_dates.package = packages.package_id
where package_id=1 and adultprice='4500'
UNION ALL
select distinct Package_id, package_title, durationindays,videourl,package_image_5 as package_image, Rating, AdultPrice
from packages
inner join
rates_and_dates on rates_and_dates.package = packages.package_id
where package_id=1 and adultprice='4500'
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, i checked it but it's generating duplicate values in all other columns. i don't want that. Just want to merge all the images columns in one column.